# OpenCV estimateRigitTransform() Matrix values

Tags: c++, opencv, math, matrix

I implemented a function that makes use of OpenCV's [estimateRigitTransform()](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html). I store the result in a OpenCV Mat called T:

```
Mat T = cv::estimateRigitTransform(image, reference, false);
```

I know that by setting the last argument to `false` I get a `partial Affine` transformation that combines rotation, scaling, translation and has 4 degrees of freedom. ('true' would output a 6 degrees of freedom fullAffine transformation that includes shearing.)

When I print the Mat `T`, I get the following result:

```
[1.050438, 0.044571, -37.17997;
 0.059126, 0.952621, -3.825856]
```

I have problems interpreting this transformation matrix. From what I understand the matrix represents the following:

```
[cos(theta)s, -sin(theta)s, tx;
 sin(theta)s,  cos(theta)s, ty]
```

which is a combination of a rotation matrix `cos() and sin()`, a scaling matrix `s` and a translation vector `tx and ty`.

So as the scaling factor `s` and the angle `theta` are constant, shouldn't the two `cos(theta)s` values be the same? In my out output one is `1.050438` and the other `0.952621`?

When I display the image transformation using OpenCV's `wrapAffine()` and passing that matrix `T`, the output seems quite reasonable but beside of that I have no possibility the check `T` for correctness.

Comment: doc says about the last parameter (false case): "Otherwise, the class of transformations to choose from is limited to combinations of translation, rotation, and uniform scaling (5 degrees of freedom)." Not sure what the fifth dof should be, so maybe there is not a uniform scaling or there are only 4 dof...

Comment: in your question you said "I know that by setting the last argument to true I get a partial Affine transformation [...]"  that's just a typo and you meant FALSE, right? Since you have to choose false if you want 4 dof.

Comment: oh, yes I mean false. I edited it. Thanks!